# Incorrect liferay-plugins dependency

Tags: gradle, dependencies, liferay, liferay-6.2

In https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/6.2.x/build-plugins.gradle#L9
following dependency is defined:

```
dependencies {
    classpath group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "portal-service", version: "7.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

How can a 6.2.x version have a dependency on 7.0.0 version? Is it a bug? When I peek to the history of the file, the dependency has always been there. I am not able to build a LF plugin and I suspect this could be the cause.

It is possible to be not related at all, but I am still curious why such dependency is there.

Comment: It might be possible, that this branch is used for development and a reference to current 7.x release is set there, even though in my mind the master branch is used. If I take a look at the tag, I can verify that there is not 6.2 GA(x) tag except for GA1. Did you try to change the version to 6.2.3 <- not sure about this, but it should be ;) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6.2 branch is mainly used for development, and those Gradle scripts are not designed to run on Liferay 6.2. Furthermore, they've been removed in the [master](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins) branch, replaced by a series of [Gradle plugins](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/master/modules/sdk/) written in Java. Everything is still under active development, but anyway you're more than welcome to try these new features and give us feedback!

For Liferay 6.2, just keep using the Ant scripts and everything should be fine!